# What is ["null"] in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am migrating an asp code to .net. I came across the following code but not sure what is it doing.

```
var collection = {};
if (typeof(collection["null"]) != "undefined" && 
    typeof(collection["null"][id]) != "undefined")
```

Can any well tell that what does collection["null"] does? If possible, how to define it in .Net

Just to give an idea, I made closedMealArea as a List in .Net

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
wildanjel

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, collection["null"] returns the property with the name "null" that is owned by the object collection. collection.null is equivalent to collection["null"].

Comment: dangerous use of the word "property" there. Everything in js is effectively a hashmap. Yes it could be a "property" of an object, but it could also be an array indexer

Comment: In JS, string indexes are properties. "Arrays" with string indexes are in fact Objects.

Comment: "collection.null is equivalent to collection["null"]." except that I don't believe collection.null is valid javascript.

Comment: ({'null':123}).null // is a valid expression and is 123

Comment: typeof null # object,  typeof window.null # undefined :)

Answer (score 2):

All the above are correct, in some way. Javascript uses two different ways of accessing properties/method on an object, or items in what is effectively its version of an associative array. As mentioned by Soubok, they are `object['propOrMethodName']` and `object.propOrMethodName`. They are equivalent.

Even a standard Array, with integer indices, can have named properties/methods. Javascript really makes no distinction on the whole. What you can't do, though, is `nonArrayObject[n]` or `arrayObject.n` where n is an integer.

In the case of the question, though, `collection` is explicitly an object:

```
var collection = {};
```

An array, with integer indices, would be declared thus:

```
var collection = [];
```

As the latter statement tests `collection["null"][n]` (assuming n is again an integer), I'd say that collection is intended to have a series of properties, each of which is an Array. One of those properties is named "null".

Comment: Actually, yes, you can do: var obj = {}; obj[3] = 42;

Comment: Oops, yes, my bad. The gotcha there is that you have a non-array object with a property named "3", but you can't use obj.3 to access it and obj.length === undefined. However, obj[3] and obj['3'] both give the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an array item.